# Переменная,значение которой хочу добавить в Label не принимается

Tags: python, tkinter, pymorphy2

```
from tkinter import *
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()


def get_vvod():
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
    value=vvod.get()
    value=int(value)
    word=morph.parse('корова')[0]
    result=word.make_agree_with_number(value).word

        

korova=Tk()
korova.title("Сколько коров?")
tk.Label(korova,text="Сколько коров?").grid(row=0,column=0)
korova.geometry("400x300")
vvod=tk.Entry(korova)
vvod.grid(row=0,column=1)
knop=tk.Button(korova,text="Преобразовать",command=get_vvod).grid(row=1,column=0)
result2=tk.Label(korova,text=(result))
result2.grid(row=2,column=1)



korova.mainloop()
```

Выдает ошибку :name 'result' is not defined

Comment: Конечно переменная не определена, это же ясно видно. Во-первых, она локальная для функции, а использовать вы её пытаетесь на глобальном уровне. А во-вторых, даже в функции она будет определена только после вызова, а вызов произойдёт только после нажатия кнопки, а не при запуске программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- На глобальном уровне пишите `result = tk.StringVar()`. Это создаст "переменную" для tkinter, которую можно использовать в виджетах.
- Создаёте Label как `result2=tk.Label(korova, textvariable=result)`.   Т.е. указываете эту "переменную" в качестве источника содержимого для виджета.
- Когда надо поменять текст в этой переменной (что автоматически отобразится
  в *Label*) вызываете у "переменной" *result* метод *set*:    `result.set(str(word.make_agree_with_number(value).word))`